# Shorten if else statement for active page link

Tags: php

I am trying to make a active page link with my following codes. But as I add more pages in the future, this if else will be much more. Is there a way to make it shorter if else ?

```
<?php  
$urlarray=explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$pageActive = end($urlarray); 
$dashClass ='';  
$userClass = '';
$settingClass = '';
$activePage = array(
    "dashboard",
    "settings",
    "users"
);

if(in_array($pageActive, $activePage)) { 
    if($pageActive == 'users'){
        $userClass = 'class="active"';
    }else if($pageActive == 'dashboard'){
        $dashClass = 'class="active"';
    }else if($pageActive == 'settings'){
        $settingClass = 'class="active"';
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
} 
?>
```

The echo html here

```
<ul>
  <li <?php echo $dashClass;?>></li>
  <li <?php echo $userClass;?>></li>
  <li <?php echo $settingClass;?>></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: you could use a ternary operator.

Comment: You cannot make it shorter if you have so many conditions to test. Why do you want to make it shorter?

Comment: what is the point of making the code shorter ? if you want to make it more readable, you can use a `switch` statement as stated by ggdx

Comment: I used this in the past: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/159854/69564

Comment: BTW I found well over a dozen duplicates asking the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

```
switch($pageActive) {
    // Users
    case 'users':
        $userClass = 'class="active"'
        break;

    // Dash
    case 'dashboard':
        $dashClass = 'class="active"'
        break;

    //something else
    case 'something-else':
        $somethingElseClass = 'class="blah"'
        break;

    // Default fallback one
    default:
        $userClass = 'class="active"';
        break;
}
```

**EDIT**
You could just do

```
<li <?php if($pageActive === 'user'){ echo 'class="active"'; } ?>User</li>
<li <?php if($pageActive === 'dashboard'){ echo 'class="active"'; } ?>>Dashboard</li>
```

Comment: Then if i have add more then page i need to add more case with your answer. But i am searching short code.

Comment: Define "short" code?

Comment: without so many `if()else if()else if()else.....`

Comment: Where's the if/else in mine?

Comment: He's talking about cases too @ggdx, he is looking for a shortcut that doesn't exist.

Comment: @ggdx you don't have if/else but if I add more pages this means that i should be add more `case 'something-else';`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thank you

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Their is already an array with list of menu items, having name as "activePage". You can try below code.

```
<?php
$urlarray=explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$pageActive = end($urlarray); 
$activePage = array('dashboard', 'settings', 'users');
?>

<ul>
    <?php
        foreach($activePage as $_key => $_value) {
            $menuSelect = '';
            if( in_array($pageActive, $activePage) ) {
                $menuSelect = 'class="active"';
            }
            ?><li <?php echo $menuSelect; ?>><?php echo $_value; ?></li><?php
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: TRUE, I guess my answer too solving the issue, without need to put much if else.